# Creating simple line drawing based on algorithm

Tags: python, algorithm, drawing, fractals

I'm new to programming and I was hoping someone could point me in the right direction on what I should learn and reserach to be able to create the program I want.

What I want is to be able to write set of rules for the program which would then create a drawing according to these rules. For example:

Draw lane segment (x lenght), copy entire existing drawing, rotate it 90 degrees, to create something like this: https://bentrubewriter.wordpress.com/2012/04/25/fractals-you-can-draw-the-dragon-curve-or-the-jurassic-fractal/

I only know basics of C and python, and never had any experience with "drawing", so I have no idea where to start. I don't need anything high res, just to create the simplest image possible - but I don't want to use ASCII. (//_| ect)

I would appreciate if someone would tell me what I should be looking at to learn how to code such a program, and which method and language would be the best and easiest for this.

Thanks for any replies in advance.

Comment: try `turtle` module. It can `turtle.forward(100)`, `turtle.left(90)` so people use it to draw fractals using recursion. http://blog.furas.pl/rysowanie-kwiatka-z-uzyciem-zolwika-w-pythonie.html

Comment: http://code.activestate.com/recipes/576982-dragon-fractal-curve/

Answer (score 1):

i think that python's turtle library would be the best for you.

code example:

```
import turtle

turtle.forward(25)
turtle.left(90)
turtle.forward(25)
turtle.right(90)
turtle.forward(25)
```

> output

[image]

[turle introduction here](https://opentechschool.github.io/python-beginners/en/simple_drawing.html)

[complete and working code here](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/576982-dragon-fractal-curve/)

Answer (score -2):

In Python, you can use the [turtle library](https://docs.python.org/2/library/turtle.html) for drawing stuff on canvas.